Mocked Jest function not found in Typescript test class
I have a test class which uses a mock. This mock is defined in 2 classes ProductSearch and ProductUpdate which have the exact mock ProductRepository mock definition. Here is the class containing the mock
 

  export class ProductRepository {
      public async findProductByCategory(){
         return await ProductCategoryModel.find({})
      }
    
  }
    ```


export class ProductSearch {
   productRepository:ProductRepository
   constructor(){
     this.productRepository = new ProductRepository()
   }

  public async findAllProductsByCategory(){
      return await this.productRepository.findProductByCategory()
     }
  }



export class ProductUpdate {
    productRepository:ProductRepository
    constructor(){
      this.productRepository = new ProductRepository()
    }   
 
 public async updateProductsByCategory(category: string ){
         const product = await 


this.productRepository.findProductByCategory()
           //update category of product
        }
      }



// I define the mock in both classes the same way like this
  

    const findProductByCategoryMock = jest.fn()
      jest.mock('../../repository/product-repository', () => {
           return {
               ProductRepository: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 
         {
                return {
                   findProductByCategory: findProductByCategoryMock,
                }
             })
          }
         })

        it('should find and update product given category',async()={
              const mockedProduct = ....
             
 

     findProductByCategoryMock.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedProduct)
            //.... rest of the test
        }
      }


Unfortunately, Jest complains with the following error at the point I call it in
ProductUpdate in method updateProductsByCategory
  TypeError: this.productRepository.findProductByCategory is not a function


The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unclear what goes wrong, how the modules are related and what test file looks like. You need to determine if a mock was applied at all. Does something change if you remove jest.mock? You potentially don't need module mocking here at all, you can mock productSearch.productRepository or ProductRepository.prototype.findProductByCategory directly

I solved it. I was using jest.resetAllMocks() in the beforeEach() lifecycle method. I was also initializing the test class instance just before that causing the the problem
